# <function details at 0x7f440740dd70>

Tags: python, django

Am a a bit new to python and django programming, can someone help me understand what's happening here
Am creating a small polls app and this is what i have

In my template `details.html`

```
 <table>
      <tr><td><a href="/polls/{{ que.id }}/up"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> </a></td></tr>
      <tr><td><a href="/polls/{{ que.id }}/up"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></td></tr>
</table>
```

That url maps to this in my `urls.py` file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns=[
     url(r'(?P<question_id>[a-z0-9A-Z]+)/(?P<method>[a-z]+)/$', views.like')
```

Then this is my `views.py`

```
def like(request, question_id, method):
    #get the question
    question = Questions.objects(id=question_id).get()
    #get the method type
    if method == 'up':
        question.likes + 1
    elif method == 'down':
        question.likes - 1
    else:
        #handle the other invalid methods
```

But on clicking the link i get this error

```
Page not found (404)    
Request Method:     GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/586748a8d6ca3f1b30ee4ff9/up/%3Cfunction%20details%20at%200x7f440740dd70%3E

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    1. ^admin/ 
    2. ^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[a-z0-9A-Z]+)/(?P<method>[a-z]+)/$ 

The current URL, polls/586748a8d6ca3f1b30ee4ff9/up/<function details at 0x7f440740dd70>, didn't match any of these.
```

So what's this function thing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does the HTML source look like?

Comment: looks exactly like the snippet in the `details.html` template.

Comment: Then are you sure you're running it through the template engine?

Comment: Looks like this ``<table >
                                        <tr><td><a href="/polls/586748a8d6ca3f1b30ee4ff9/up"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> </a></td></tr>
                                        
                                        <tr><td><a href="/polls/586748a8d6ca3f1b30ee4ff9/up"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></td></tr>
                                    </table>``

Comment: Did you notice that the URLs in the template don't end in a "/", but the urls.py entries do?

Comment: Oh Sure. Let me try and change that and see if it works

Comment: Still receiving the same `<function details at 0x7f440740dd70>` appending at the end of my url

Comment: Make sure you don't have any other urls.py entry in your entire project that could possibly match the URL.

Comment: Non atall, Only two entries. One matches the index page. This `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')` and the next one is the like entry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132001/discussion-between-void-shad-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Comment: `question.likes + 1` ? it does nothing... and that: `url(r'(?P<question_id>[a-z0-9A-Z]+)/(?P<method>[a-z]+)/$', views.like')` is incorrect (stray quote in the end)

Comment: How do i increment the likes in the mongo database when one clicks the up button